# G-suite Sync all organization calendar and mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I would like to be able to sync g-suite entire user's emails and calendars.

Is there is an option to use organization admin oath and use api to read only request?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you checked [Google Sync](https://support.google.com/a/answer/135937)?

Comment: I need to get access to my customer organization, not mine . So I want customer admin to use aouth so I will be able to get mails and calendars using api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Domain-wide delegation of authority` is what you would need to achieve it. 
 Here is  [official link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) for steps to follow to perform domain wide delegation.